# how to draw an array of circles in a straight line, in the bottom of the browser window

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a straight line of circles using d3 at the bottom of the browser window.  I am not sure how this would be accomplished.  I know I could create a bunch of circles using the SVG tag, but there's probably a better way using a for loop with an array.

I would like the circles to appear in a straight line at the bottom of the browser window.  I would also like the circles to fill the width of the browser window as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the importance of an array? Is it the circle radius? or what? How many circles do you need? How much gap must be there between the circles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = 100;

d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
  .selectAll('circle')
    .data(d3.range(0, width, width/10)).enter()
  .append('circle')
    .style('fill', 'red')
    .attr('r', height/4)
    .attr('cy', height/2)
    .attr('cx', function(d){ return d; })
```

Comment: While this answers the question, it would be great if you could add some explanatory text.

Answer (score 2):

d3 has a functional style with the concept of selectors. If you are thinking of using a loop then you are probably using the tool wrong. The functional style allows you to instead concentrate on what you want to do with each item of data instead of how to process the data. There are also a number of helper functions.

Lets take Adam's solution

```
d3.select('body')
```

We are using CSS style selectors to select one object from the DOM. In this case it is the body of the document. We can do a number of things with this selection but first we append using

```
append('svg')
```

in

```
d3.select('body').append('svg')
```

This could be written to differently if we needed to reuse these selections

```
var body = d3.select('body');
var svg = body.append('svg');
```

We can the define the attributes of the object just defined

```
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
```

Now comes the interesting bit. D3 operates by binding data to selections so add data we first need a (probably) empty selection.

```
.selectAll('circle')
```

Note the use of `selectAll` not `select`.

Adam creates an array of data with

```
 d3.range(0, width, width/10)
```

This uses one of d3's helper functions which behaves like the range function found in many languages with functional support (examples of use in [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370568.aspx) & [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range))

```
> d3.range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

> d3.range(0,5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

> d3.range(4,5)
[4]

// At intervals of 2 
>d3.range(0,5,2)
[0, 2, 4]
```

Anyway we have a list of number which gets bound using

```
.data()
```

Which returns a selection. We the define what happens within the life cycle events of this selection. Because we are only dealing with data entering we can just go

```
.enter()
```

Anything under this selection will be applied to any datum entering (which in this case will be all the elements from the list). You should be able to understand what is happening until

```
.attr('cx', function(d){ return d; })
```

What is happening hear is the attribute `cx` is dependent on the data from the list we supplied earlier. We can provide a function which will be executed which gets passed the `datum` and the `index` of the current item.

---

### Using some more of the helpers D3 brings

Typically you will need to use the `scale` helper when using D3. This allows us to abstract out the concept of pixels and instead concentrate on a fixed range.

Slightly changing the example given by Adam. Lets say we want to show 5 evenly spaced circles at the end of the document.

We can define the data like

```
 var data = d3.range(0, 5);
```

And set up a scale like

```
 var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, data.length])
    .range([0,width])
```

With the domain (that is the input) been 0 to the max number of our data.

```
.domain([0, d3.max(data)])
```

and the range (that is what we want to output) as been 0 up to the maximum number of pixals

```
.range([0,width])
```

The example code would then look like

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = 100;
var data = d3.range(0, 5);
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, data.length-1])
     .range([0,width])

d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
  .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data ).enter()
  .append('circle')
    .style('fill', 'red')
    .attr('r', height/4)
    .attr('cy', height/2)
    .attr('cx', function(d){ return x(d);})
```

We can even change that last line to

```
.attr('cx', function(d, i){ return x(i);})
```

Whilst in this example the index and the data is the same this allows us to to space out the items whilst keeping the data simple. Say if the array actually was the values which r should be

```
...
var data = [4,1,20,5,7];
...
.attr('r', function(d){ return d;})
...
.attr('cx', function(d, i){ return x(i+0.5);})
```